# How do I remove multiple characters in a string

Tags: regex, string, powershell, expression

I've been trying to find the best way to string together a remove command, but I'm not understanding how to do this in one string vs multiple...
I'm wanting to remove all spaces and all underscores; I know I can do them individually like this:

```
$Name = "\Test Name\Test_Underscore 1_2"
$NameFull1 = $NAME -replace '\s'
$NameFull2 = $NameFull1 -replace '_',''
```

And have an output like this:

```
TestNameTestUnderscore12
```

However I'm wanting to just do it once, but I'm not sure how to combine them (I've been looking around for a while now and can't find an answer).

I was thinking it would look like this (and I've tried a few other ways as well), but keep running into an error...

```
$Name = "\Test Name\Test_Underscore 1_2"
$NameFull = $NAME -replace '\s' | '_',''
```

Comment: Maybe `$NameFull1 = $NAME -replace '[\s_]'`? It results in `\TestName\TestUnderscore12`. Do you want to replace ``\`` or not?

Comment: Yeah, I want to replace all backslashes in the string.

Comment: Please check my answer, I showed the most efficient way to do that with a regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest putting the characters you need to remove into a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`. You could use this in `gr[ae]y` to match either `gray` or `grey`.

Code:

```
PS> $Name = "\Test Name\Test_Underscore 1_2"
PS> $NameFull1 = $NAME -replace '[\s_\\]+'
PS> $NameFull1
TestNameTestUnderscore12
```

The `[\s_\\]` will match either whitespace, `_` or `\`.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I didn't understand how to link the two together, but Character Classes works perfectly for this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The pipe symbol (`|`) must be *inside* the string for an alternation:

```
$NameFull = $NAME -replace '\s|_', ''
```